# SQLError 19 UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, cordova, network-programming

I am getting this error when setting up my app, creating a local database and simply inserting the **first** and **only** user (who has logged in locally). Please see comment in code for where I get the error message.

```
angular.module("greenApp")
.service("dbService",['$q', function($q){

    var db;
    var promise = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        db = window.openDatabase('greenDB', '1.0', 'Green Database', 2*1024*1024);

        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (user TEXT PRIMARY KEY) ")
        }, function(err){
            alert('Something went wrong... Error: DATABASE INIT ' + err);
        }, function(scc){
            deferred.resolve();
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    promise();

    var query = function(sql, args) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(sql, args, function(tx, results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var insert_into = function(args) {
        var queryPromise = query("INSERT INTO user (user) VALUES (?)", args);
        console.log("in insert_into", queryPromise) // Error message comes here
        return queryPromise;
    };

    return {
        promise: promise,
        insert_into: insert_into,
    };
}]);
```

Where `args` is simply `["user-name-string"]`, I get an error message that says:

> "could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (19 UNIQUE
>   constraint failed: user.user)

Any ideas what could have happened? Exactly the same code was running and working in a recent pure cordova project which I just ported to Ionic.

Comment: can u show the table structure also which dbms are u using

Comment: r u trying to insert the same text already there in the table? can u show some example?

Comment: I'd throw a console.log statement directly inside your insert_into method and double check to make sure args is what you expect it to be and not, for example, null.

Comment: Thanks but I have done that, args is as expected and exactly as stated in the question..

Comment: is `user` the column name?

Comment: I have no idea. This is all the code regarding the DB.

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword in sql. Can you try changing that column name to something else?

Comment: thanks, I changed **USERS** to **ALL_USERS** and **user** to **usr**. Still same error though: _"could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (19 UNIQUE constraint failed: ALL_USERS.usr)"_

Comment: Please could you try changing to `var queryPromise = query("INSERT INTO user (user) VALUES (?)", args);` (i.e. remove the `sql`).

Comment: @SteveChambers sorry something got wrong when I wrote the question, in the real case there was no sql in the string. It's edited now.

Comment: Does it happen without the log statement?

Comment: When you run it on an empty database table, and look into the table afterwards, are there zero or one row in there?  If it is inserting twice, there should be one row in the table after it is run.  If there are zero rows, then either it isn't inserting twice or you aren't committing until after all commands have run.

Comment: @GuySchalnat when to look into the table afterwards, do you simply mean logging my db object? In that case it seems to be empty all the time. Even after the insertion.

Comment: Try to uninstall your app to clean the db and see if that's not an issue caused by the fact that the db persists when you exit the app (and so you run the same insert  each time)

Comment: This function returns the insert_into function to its caller.  Is it possible the caller is invoking that function more than once?  Can you post the calling code?

Comment: @QuickFix you're probably right. The error must be because the db wasn't empty at first. If you write an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite db persists when you exit the app, so each time you start the app it will try to do the insert. (I gess it worked at first launch and you got the error the second time).

As you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` the app does not fail on table creation but on the first insert.

You can use the pragma user_version to read/write version of your database and so know in wich case you have to create tables / insert values or if the db is already ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are inserting twice in your code ... here

```
var insert_into = function(args) {

    var queryPromise = query("INSERT INTO user (user) VALUES (?)", args);
    console.log("in insert_into", queryPromise) // Error message comes here
    return query("INSERT INTO user (user) VALUES (?)", args); <-- you did a query above, now you do it again?!?
};
```

Comment: yeah sorry that was really bad written. the error comes above the second query though.. edited the question again still the same error.

Comment: if you rewrite your code before posting it here, we might have a hard time finding the issue that's bothering you.

Comment: yes - but who knows what else you re-written? Rewriting stuff introduces new sources of errors. That's my point.